# Craft CMS 4 & Enupal Stripe Payment Plugin - Production Environment Issue

Tags: craftcms

I've installed the Enupal Stripe payments plugin on my Craft CMS 4 website. It's working well locally but when I try to create a payment form on the production environment I get this error:

Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'hugoand_friends_production.matrixcontent_enupalmultipleplans' doesn't exist...

I'm pretty new to custom development so I'm a bit lost but it looks like the database changes that happened when I installed the plugin are not being reflected on the production environment? Any ideas how I can fix it? My site is hosted with Servd Host which I think provides a separate database for production.